# htaccess - file is sending to another domain

Tags: .htaccess

We are moving our company's websites to a new server. We have a website set up whose job is to create short links. I am trying to test it is making the transition ok before we move the domain name across but the htaccess file is causing problems.

We are accessing the new sites using 'http://ipaddress/~siteonnewserver/'

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~siteonnewserver/

SetEnv TZ Europe/London

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?link=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I have been able to rule out index.php as being the issue (by deleting the htaccess and visiting the index file with link=thisisalink)

When the htaccess is there it tries to send the request to our domain instead of keeping it on the new server.

Is it also possible that this is not a htaccess problem but something to do with it being set up as domain.com on whm and cpanel?

Comment: The problem is most likely the server config not the htaccess file itself. It sounds like the server hosts several websites, set up as virtual hosts. If that is the case, if you specify just an IP Address when connecting to the machine you will get sent to the default host, which is usually the first virtual host specified in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Just edit your local hosts-file to temporarily point the domainname to the new servers IP. This way you can test the new server without changing the DNS setting.